# how could i build app locker by react-native?

Tags: react-native, mobile

I searched a lot about accessing the device app inside my react-native app and locking specific apps with a password but could not get results.
Is it possible to use react native to create app access device apps and lock and unlock them?

Answer (score 0):

To build an app locker with React Native, you can use the `react-native-app-locker` package:

1. Import AppLocker from react-native-app-locker
2. Lock the app with AppLocker.lockApp('com.facebook.katana')

You can also use the `react-native-lock-android` package:

1. Run `npm install --save react-native-lock-android` to add the
   package to your app's dependencies
2. Add **LockReactPackage** to the **ReactInstanceManager** in the onCreate
   method of the MainActivity